# Extracting MDX calculated members' values

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

Does anyone know of a way to "extract" the formulas for all calculated members of a cube into some kind of flat, readable file? Alternatively, a less-painful method of getting an overview of the code than using Analysis Services' Cube Editor and clicking on each Calculated Member would be helpful. Yes, I'm new to MDX. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what "Registered User" was referring to - but it won't answer your question if I'm understanding it correctly.

olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/

Fortunately, if I understand your question correctly, there is a very simple solution. When you are using BIDS against your cube, on the "Calculated Members" tab, click on the 12th icon from the left which is "Script View" - I think this is what you are looking for.

ssas-info.com/images/fbfiles/images/calc_tab.jpg

Credit to ssas-info for the image (can't embed or post links because of my "reputation" - doesn't make sense, but ok).

Comment: I had never heard of BIDS, but it looks like this could be what I was looking for. Unfortunately, we are using an ancient version of MS SQL/SSAS, so no BIDS, but many thanks!

Comment: 8 (not as in 2008), and we don't have Visual Studio (any version) either. Considering the upgrade costs, i think i'm just SOL for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to the OLAP cube via an Excel pivot table, then you can use the Olap Tools -> Convert to Formulas feature to expose the underlying cube formulas.  I would recommend doing it for the smallest possible data because Excel will issue a large number of discovery requests to the OLAP server.  Please note I don't have any calculated measures, so I couldn't test if it actually does this...

Comment: thanks for your answer... unfortunately, there are a couple hundred calculated members, each member I added to the pivot table took longer and longer to add,so I stopped after 3 or 4 -- I also failed to find "Convert to Formulas" tool for those that I had already added. There is a very distinct possibility that I am misunderstanding you, however, newbie to this that I am. We currently connect via Excel macros to a SQL database.